# Can't pass variable from one job to another (Azure Devops Pipelines)

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am trying to pass a variable from a job to a job, the structure is simple: 1 stage, 2 jobs within, 1st job having multiple tasks. The variable in question is `reportUrl`. I'm passing it to a bash shell that's supposed to send it to a Teams webhook. The webhook works fine. The summarized pipeline looks like this:

```
stages:
  - stage: SmokeTests
    displayName: Smoke Tests
    jobs:

      - job: E2ETests
        displayName: E2E Tests
        condition: and(succeeded(), not(contains(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], 'skip ci')))
        pool: xxx-$(ENV_NAME)-e2e
        steps:
      - checkout: self
      - checkout: E2ETests

          - task: AWSShellScript@1
            displayName: Upload Allure report
            name: upload_allure_report8
            condition: always()
            inputs:
              awsCredentials: $(IT_CONNECTION_NAME)
              regionName: $(REGION)
              scriptType: "inline"
              #this works fine, I can see the URL
              inlineScript: |
                set -e
                export REPORT_URL=https://${ALLURE_S3_BUCKET}/${{parameters.ALLURE_REPORT_ENV}}/$(Build.BuildNumber)/index.html
                echo Report URL: ${REPORT_URL}
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=reportUrl;isOutput=true;]${REPORT_URL}"

      - job: SendNotificationPass
        displayName: 'Send Teams Notification - Succeeded'
        dependsOn: E2ETests
        condition: eq(dependencies.E2ETests.result, 'succeeded')
        variables:
          reportUrl: $[ stageDependencies.SmokeTests.E2ETests.outputs['upload_allure_report8.reportUrl'] ]
        steps: |
          echo "E2E test status: PASSED. The report URL is ${{ variables.reportUrl }}"
          MESSAGE="{\"text\": \"E2E test status: PASSED. The report URL is: ${{ variables.reportUrl }}\"}"
          curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$MESSAGE" $(WEBHOOK)
```

Getting to the SendNotificationPass job, I get this:

```
/home/vsts/work/_temp/xxx.sh: line 2: stageDependencies.SmokeTests.E2ETests.outputs['upload_allure_report8.reportUrl'] : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".SmokeTests.E2ETests.outputs['upload_allure_report8.reportUrl'] ")
```

I have tried many different things - using `dependencies` instead of `stageDependencies`, not having the stage there, but just the job, ie `dependencies.E2ETests.outputs`, etc. Running out of ideas. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about azure, but I see that the error message refers to a script named `xxx.sh`. Is this a script generated by azure? The statement the error refers to, is obviously incorrect in bash, but  how was this script generated?

Comment: read the steps section of SendNotificationPass, thats the script

Comment: As I said, I don't know Azure; however, it looks like the  shell script generated from this step uses `stageDependencies.SmokeTests.E2ETests.outputs[...]` as a shell variable name, and this of course is not a valid name. I guess you want Azure to expand this variable (perhaps this is what the syntax `${{ .. }}` is supposed to do?), before generating this script, and the error message tells us that this does not happen. Do you have a similar **working** Azure definition, which also defines and uses such a variable, and which you can use for comparision?